# Add template to custom adminhtml button

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, adminhtml, javascript, controllers

I am currently creating a button for a single order in Magento(next to invoice, ship, reorder etc.). I would like the button to link to a javascript function inside a template with variables from that order passed to the function.

The way I currently have is I call a custom controller which goes to a new        page(`"setLocation('{$block->getUrl('*/shiprush_orderbutton/indexaction')}')"`).

Is there any way I could avoid this and just call the function straight on the click of the button.

app\code\local\MyApp\OrderButton\etc\config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyApp_OrderButton>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </MyApp_OrderButton>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <myapp_orderbutton>
            <class>MyApp_OrderButton_Model</class>
        </myapp_orderbutton>
    </models>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <myapp_orderbutton before="Mage_Adminhtml">
                        MyApp_OrderButton_Adminhtml
                        </myapp_orderbutton>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <observers>
                <myapp_orderbutton>
                    <class>myapp_orderbutton/observer</class>
                    <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </myapp_orderbutton>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    </events>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <orderbutton>
                <file>mybutton.xml</file>
            </orderbutton>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\mybutton.xml

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTemplate><template>shiprush/sales/order/view/info.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

app\code\local\MyApp\OrderButton\Model\Observer.php:

```
class MyApp_OrderButton_Model_Observer {
public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event) {

    $block = $event->getBlock();
    $magemodel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
    $orderid = $magemodel->getIncrementId();
    $order = $magemodel->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
        // $block->prepareLayout();
        $block->addButton('do_something_crazy', array(
            'label'     => 'my button',
            'onclick'   => "setLocation('{$block->getUrl('*/myapp_orderbutton/indexaction')}')",
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));           
    }
}
}
```

app\code\local\MyApp\OrderButton\controllers\Adminhtml\ButtonController.php:

```
class MyApp_OrderButton_Adminhtml_ButtonController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

Comment: What does the `setLocation` look like after it gets added to the DOM? You've got those curly braces there and are calling a PHP method in the context of Javascript.

Comment: @qwerty123.. you could try using ajax and do something like `'onclick'   => "new Ajax.Request('$block->getUrl('*/myapp_orderbutton/indexaction')"`

Comment: @R.S if I do a simple alert("x") inside the onclick js, it allows it, but it doesn't let me add external src or functions, how would I do this

Comment: @R.S tried both, with the whole function I got: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'https' (T_STRING), expecting ')' because I tried adding an external source that the function relies on. if I just did function(){alert("x")}, nothing happened when I clicked the button

Comment: Try `'onclick' => "(function(e){ alert('x'); })(event)",`

Comment: @R.S ya, that works, now I just need to add the src, where can I put that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you want to happen when the button is click?

Comment: @R.S I'm trying to call a function that relies on an external js file. How could I reference that external file(src="www.mysite.com/myfile.js").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have created a custom module for this, in your config.xml add

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <magepal module="magepal">
                <file>magepal.xml</file>
            </magepal>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

JS file location

```
skin/adminhtml/default/default/[companyName]/[moduel]/js/my.js
```

In magepal.xml add

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="head">
         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>[companyName]/[module]/js/my.js</sc‌​ript></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Then call the function from your block

```
$block->addButton('do_something_crazy', array(
   'label'     => 'my button',
   'onclick'   => "(function(e){callMyFunction()}'; })(event)",
   'class'     => 'go'
));
```

Comment: where should the path of the js file be? Starting from app where do I navigate to? Thanks

Comment: Assuming your js file is in  skin/adminhtml/default/default/[companyName]/[moduel]/js/my.js`<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>[companyName]/[module]/js/my.js</script></action>`

Comment: no, that didn't work, I put the xml layout file in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout and put the js file where you said. Nothing was triggered(made a simple alert in the new function).

Comment: View page source, is the file included?

Comment: yes, the source given is http://localhost/magento/js/MyApp/OrderButton/js/my.js

Comment: So how do I add the php variables from the observer to this new javascript file and how would I add a nonlocal file(www.example.com/my.js), thanks

Comment: Please update your question and add the current config.xml and layout.xml

Comment: so I need to have a button on the page and it to execute js, but a template would work much better than just a js file, because external css and js inclusions are needed, with this I get the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCreatedAtDate() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\app\sales\order\view\info.phtml

Comment: Where is the code to add the javascript in mybutton.xml

Comment: I got rid of it, i am going a different route. I am trying to convert it to a template now that overrides the info.phtml in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view, which I will then put the javascript in