# Custom Adminhtml Controller Post to Template

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, controllers

I have a file mytemp.phtml that I make a post request in and I would like this controller to retrieve it, then pass it back to mytemp.phtml. My controller is not being read by Magento though and I can't find my error. Also, once I get it to be read how do I pass that post retrieval to mytemp.phtml, thanks

config.xml:

```
<config>
    <-- other -->
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyApp_MyModule_Adminhtml</mymodule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <!--other-->
</config>
```

MyApp\MyModule\controllers\Adminhtml\ButtonController.php:

```
class MyApp_MyModule_Adminhtml_ButtonController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a admin layout.xml in  app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/myapp_mymodule.xml (update your config.xml as needed see [Add template to custom adminhtml button](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72833/add-template-to-custom-adminhtml-button))

```
<layout>
    <mymodule_adminhtml_button_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/button" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/button.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mycompany_adminhtml_mymodule_index>
</layout>
```

In your controller save the post variable using register

```
class MyApp_MyModule_Adminhtml_ButtonController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        //normally you would post to a new action
        if($this->getRequest()->getPost('param')){
           Mage::register('mymodule_data', $this->getRequest()->getPost('param'));  // or $this->getRequest()->getPost();
         }

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Then in your  block (mymodule/button) check to see if `Mage::registry('mymodule_data');` exist and display it in your phtml file accordingly